# Why API do not execute loop task - FastAPI, Celery?

Tags: python, celery, fastapi

I have an API that is responsible for building a database model based on the address passed to it. There are hundreds of such models, and I don't want to do it manually, so I decided to create an API that, when called, will loop through all the addresses and pass them to build the model.

**I use:** FastAPI, Celery

**Celery task**

```py
from agents.walletReputation import WalletReputation

@app.task(name="walletReputation")
def wallet_reputation(id: str):
    WalletReputation(id).add_reputation_to_db()

    return {"message": "Success"}
```

**Generator to yield item from FB**

```py
def all_addresses_generator():
    for row in session.query(DbNcTransaction).all():
        yield row
```

**My endpoints**

```py
# Make or update one wallet
@router.post("/run/{id}")
async def create_or_update(id: str):
    wallet_reputation.delay(id)

    return {"Status": "Task successfully add to execute"}

# Make or update all wallets
@router.post("/run/all")
async def create_or_update_all():
    for address in all_addresses_generator():
        wallet_reputation.delay(address)

    return {"Status": "Task successfully add to execute"}
```

Do you have any idea why the first endpoint works and the second one doesn't anymore?

Comment: Could you be more specific than 'doesn't work?'.

Comment: Literally, nothing happens. In the logs it doesn't rash errors, it looks like the task was added to Celery but didn't execute properly.